# In an abstract class does the "this" keyword refrerence the parent or child class?

Tags: java, this, abstract

I have an abstract class Flight. Flight contains the method schedule() which calls the private method schedule(final Flight f)

```
public void schedule()
{
    schedule(this);
}

private void schedule(final Flight f)
{
    new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            f.checkIn();
            updateList();
        }
    }, this.getDate());
}
```

Lets now say I have a class SouthWestFlight that extends Flight

```
Flight f = new SouthWestFlight(); //ignore the missing params doesn't matter for example
f.schedule();
```

Would this pass the instance of the Flight or the instance of SouthWestFlight as a parameter in the schedule method?

Comment: When I asked this it would not let me as I did not have enough reputation. I have done it now. Thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Would this pass the instance of the Flight or the instance of
>   SouthWestFlight as a parameter in the schedule method?

The instance of `Flight` it's exactly the instance of `SouthWestFlight`. You **don't** have 2 different instances. Your SoutWestFlight instance *IS A* Flight. Actually you can't have a `Flight` instance itself cause it's abstract.

Answer (score 3):

The instance of `Flight` and `SouthhWestFlight` are actually the same instance. There is only one instance to pass, and it will be passed.

Comment: I know you can't manually instaniate an abstract class in your code but does the JVM instaniate it? I always thought calling super in your constructor would construct two objects, one of the parent and one of the child.

Comment: No, there's only one object that gets constructed. It looks like two objects are being constructed, but only one object is actually created.

Comment: The JVM doesn't instantiate abstract classes. The only way to get an object of an abstract class is to instantiate a subclass of it.

Comment: That answers two of my questions. Thank you very much for your comments.

Answer (score 2):

I've prepared a simple test app.

```
public class TEST {

    static abstract class Flight {
        String type = "Flight";
        abstract String getDirection();
        public String getType() {
            return this.type;
        }
        public void schedule() {
            System.out.printf("Scheduled a %s towards %s",this.getType(),this.getDirection());
            System.out.println();
            System.out.printf("ReadyToGo: %s",this.isReadyToGo());
        }
        public boolean isReadyToGo() {
            return false;
        }
    }

    static class SouthWestFlight extends Flight {
        String type = "SouthWestFlight";
        @Override
        String getDirection() {
            return "SouthWest";
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isReadyToGo() {
            return true;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        new SouthWestFlight().schedule();
    }
}
```

**Output:**
Scheduled a Flight towards SouthWest
ReadyToGo: true

**Conclusions**
Here the `SouthWestFlight` object is still a `Flight` Object.
But when you extend a class the child class overrides all the methods of parent class.
That is why `isReadyToGo()` of SouthWestFlight() returned true.
None of the properties are overriden.
That is why `this.getType()` returns `Flight`.
But if you override the `getType()` method with a new method in `SouthWestFlight` like this:

```
@Override
public String getType() {
   return this.type;
}
```

It will return `type` field of `SouthWestFlight`. Wondering why?
It is because, the first `getType()` method is defined in parent `class Flight`. So it returns `type` field of `class Flight`. The second `getType()` method is defined in `SouthWestFlight` so it returns `type` field of `SouthWestFlight`.

Hope you've got it clear. Please comment if you found any mistake or got any doubt.