# Why "THIS" keyword denotes Child object into Parent class's method?

Tags: java, inheritance, this

I'm using Child and Parent relationship using Inheritance. I had written a code where I use 'THIS' keyword in a method of Parent class and the same method is overridden in my Child class. When I call Parent class method from Child class overridden method using 'Super' keyword then in Parent class method, the 'THIS' keyword denotes Child object class, and when I call a method from Parent class method using 'THIS' keyword then It call Child class method(this method is same and also available in Parent & Child Class using overriding).

```
    class Parent {

    void onResume() {
        println("Parent:OnResume" + this) // Here 'this' denotes Child class's Object

        this.show() // here Child class's method is invoked
        show()      // here Child class's method is invoked as well
    }

    void show() {
        println("Parent:Show")
    }

}

class Child extends Parent {

    override 
    void onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        println("Child:->OnResume" + this)
    }

    override 
    void show() {
        println("Child:Show")
    }

}

//Calling code
Parent parentRef = new Child()
parentRef.onResume()
```

If I create an Object of Child class using Parent class reference variable like

```
Parent parentRef = new Child()
```

then 'this' denotes Child object in onResume() method of Parent class and when we call show() method in Parent then it call Child class's show() method.

Please let me clear why it happens so. As I know 'this' refers Current object of the class so here why 'this' refers Child object from Parent class.
Please provide deep and internal details for this reason. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no `THIS` keyword. There is however the [`this` keyword](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.3), which denotes the *current* object when an instance method is invoked. In this case it is clearly a instance of `Child`. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Here are two Objects one is Child object that I've created and another is Parent class object that is created internally. So here why Parent class object is not referred in Parent class using 'this' keyword ?

Comment: Closely related: [In an abstract class does the “this” keyword refrerence the parent or child class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18939597/in-an-abstract-class-does-the-this-keyword-refrerence-the-parent-or-child-clas) Perhaps a duplicate? Or of [Inheritance and the “this” keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5155811/inheritance-and-the-this-keyword)

Comment: *Please provide deep and internal details for this reason.* It’s not because of any internal reasons. It’s because the language spec says so.

Answer (score 6):

`this` references the current instance. If you create an instance of `Child`, the runtime type of `this` is `Child`, regardless of whether you write `this` in the parent class code or the child class code.

And if you call `this.someMethod()` in the `Parent` class code, if `someMethod` is overridden by `Child` class, the `Child` class method will be executed.

Comment: Please correct me If I'm wrong, as I know when we create a Child class object then internally Parent class object is also created so why 'this' does not denotes Parent object into parent class ? or please tell me if any other concept is applied for it?

Comment: @SaadBinIqbal you created a `Child` instance with `new Child()`. This instance has properties of both the `Child` class and the `Parent` class, but its runtime type is `Child`. Therefore the runtime type of `this` is always `Child`.

Comment: @SaadBinIqbal only 1 object is created

Answer (score 0):

When you override a method, you overwrite the functionality of the overridden method.... *unless* the child class calls `super.show()` from somewhere. In other words, the child is in full control of whether the original (overridden) functionality is still available or not *and* from where it is available. (The child is not limited to calling `super.show()` from within the overridden `show()` but may call it from other methods and constructors as well!)